# Convert float to custom Fixed point data type

Tags: c#, numbers, bit-manipulation

I have a fixed point data type:

```
public struct Fixed
{
    public const long SCALE = 1_000_000_000;
    private readonly long unscaledValue;

    public static explicit Fixed(double value)
    {
        // Halp
    }

    public static explicit double(Fixed value)
    {
        // Halp
    }
}
```

So, to represent 5.2, `unscaledValue` would be 5 200 000 000.
What would be the best way to convert `float`s and `double`s to my data type, and the reverse?

Comment: Does it has to be a decimal based fixedpoint data type?

Comment: Yes. I need exact representations of numbers such as 0.1, 0.01...

Comment: Why use this over `Decimal`?

Comment: But since `0.1` can't be exactly represented as a `double` I don't see a chance to correctly convert it. Isn't `decimal` an option?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have a good reason. Even so, I'd like to know how to implement something like this.

Comment: Copy the source code for decimal. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Decimal.cs

Comment: @Ackdari, I'd like to have these conversions to be as close as possible, but I don't expect them to be exact

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

```
long fix = (long) value * scale;
```

for the conversion to your type and something like this

```
double value = ((double) fix)/((double)scale);
```

for the reconversion.

But be aware of precision lost and that if you want to multiply two numbers of your type you need to rescale either the operants or the result

e.g.

```
long fix3 = (fix1 * fix2)/scale;
```

Comment: the moment I cast value to long, I loose all the information past the dacimal point. Also, casting fix to double can result in an overflow.